# Couldn't Locate the Delete Project Permission

Tags: azure-devops

I am in the Permission section of my organization settings in Azure DevOps and I was trying to search for the **Delete Project** permission, but I couldn't find it.

[image]

Is it the **Delete this node** permission?

Answer (score 0):

No. The **Delete this node** permission is unrelated to the **Delete team project** permission.

The image you have provided is showing permissions at the Collection level.

From "[Delete a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/delete-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)" - "[Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/delete-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#prerequisites)":

> You must be a member of the **Project Administrators** group or have the project-level **Delete team project** permission set to **Allow**. Organization owners are automatically members of this group. For more information, see [Change project-level permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/change-project-level-permissions?view=azure-devops).

I'm guessing that you are not a member of the **Project Administrators** group and the **Delete team project** permission is hidden from you at the Collection level.

Check if you have permission at the project level for the specific project. See "[Change project-level permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/change-project-level-permissions?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)" for reference.

Comment: I checked my permissions, and I am a member of the Project Administrators group. Still, I couldn't see the Delete Project permission. The original organization owner of the DevOps organization left and transferred the role to me. Do you think this could have caused it?